# Function help for java game store coins

Tags: java

Im newish to java and I would like to add a store to  my game, I made a function so that when the button U is pressed the coins that are won are used and it costs 50 but how do I make it so that it only uses them when there are 50 and doesnt allow you to use them if you have less.

```
if(i == KeyEvent.VK_U) {
        wonCoins = wonCoins - 50;
        RenderPanel.clickedButton = true;
        }
```

Comment: `if(i == KeyEvent.VK_U && wonCoins >= 50)`

Comment: Can you explain what thats doing, im a noob at programming, still learning :) thanks for the help though.

Comment: It checks that the key pressed is "u" (`i == KeyEvent.VK_U`), and that the number of coins is at least 50 (`wonCoins >= 50`). If those two conditions are met, it executes the code inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The Operator you need is the && which is Java for "AND"

It's opposite is "||" which is "OR"

Using those you can combine multiple checks into a single if statement.

In logical terms:

If KeyDown = U and wonCoins > 50 Then

Resueman's code example is a good one

if(i == KeyEvent.VK_U && wonCoins >= 50)